# external <iframe> blog being overlapped by current blog footer template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have embedded an iframe blog space to my shopify blog. Problem is that when the page loads up now the footer overlaps how the actual page should look rather than just tagging on to the end of the container or `<div>`.
Can anyone help? I'm pretty new and novice to this and have followed many threads trying to rectify but the result stays the same.

This is the embedded code that is in the content:

```
<iframe src="https://bedfordguitars.exposure.co/?embed=true" style="width: 100%; height: 550px; margin-bottom: 0px; border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 2px;">
</iframe><br />
<a href="https://exposure.co" style="text-transform: uppercase;"></a>

<!-- <div class="grid"> <div class="unit legal-content"> <div> --> {{ page.content }} <!-- </div> </div> </div> -->
```

Comment: please add some code. also try to recreate the issue in jsfiddle or simiar.

Comment: OK So this is my iframe that im trying to embed into my shopify page which i'll add the code to underneath <iframe src="https://bedfordguitars.exposure.co/?embed=true" style="width: 100%; height: 550px; margin-bottom: -10px; border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 2px;"></iframe><br /><a href="https://exposure.co" style="text-transform: uppercase;"></a>

Comment: <!--     <div class="grid">
  <div class="unit legal-content">
          <div> -->
    {{ page.content }}
<!--           </div>
      </div>
</div> -->

Comment: The second is the general page template.

Comment: This is the liquid code theme.liquid